# Functional equation $x f(y) -y f(x) =f(\dfrac{y}{x})$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R},x\neq 0$ then $$x f(y) -y f(x) =f(\dfrac{y}{x}).$$
*My try*:

Let $x=1$ then $f(y) -y f(1) = f(y) \Rightarrow f(1) =0.$

Let $y=1\Rightarrow x f(1) - f(x) = f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\Rightarrow f(x) = f\left(-\dfrac{1}{x}\right).$

Let $y=0,x=2\Rightarrow 2 \cdot f(0) = f(0)\Rightarrow f(0) =0.$

Let $y=xy\Rightarrow x f(xy) - xy f(x) = f(y).$

Let $x=y$ then the above function we have $y f(y^2) -y^2 f(y) =f(y).$

Try $y=-1$ in $y f(y^2) -y^2 f(y) =f(y)$ we have $f(-1) =0;$

Let $y=-1$ in $x f(y) -y f(x) =f(\dfrac{y}{x})$ we have that $f(x) = -f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$

Thus, $f\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)=-f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$

I don't know what to do next? Help me!

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377447/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks sir, I didn't see that question when I ask, sorry.